# Accessing data created from service within other components throws call stack size exceeded Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making an angular website in which I need to retrieve a bunch of data from a service and pass around to multiple components.

Originally I had this service simply getting a

`Observable<Itinerary[]>`(itinerary is just a model I made to collect the right bits of info)

So I did this in the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Itinerary } from 'src/app/Models/itineary';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItineraryService {
  apiUrl = 'this is my url here'

 
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(){
   return = this._http.get<Itinerary[]>(this.apiUrl);
  
}
```

I would then call this in a component and loop over it to break it down into smaller arrays which were stored in each component.

I do not think this is a good way to achieve this. So I then essentially did what I was doing in each component within the service and planned to just access the arrays directly from here.

So I did this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Itinerary } from 'src/app/Models/itineary';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItineraryService {
  apiUrl = 'this is myurl'

  itinerarys: Observable<Itinerary[]>;

  all: Itinerary;
  updatedBy: Itinerary;
  hotelBookings: Itinerary;
  items: Itinerary;
  itineraryId: Itinerary;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(){
   this.itinerarys= this._http.get<Itinerary[]>(this.apiUrl);
    this.itinerarys.forEach(obj => {
      Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {

        this.all = value;
         if (key == "hotelBookings"){
           
          this.hotelBookings = value;
          
        }else if (key == "itineraryId")
        {
          this.itineraryId = value;

        }else if (key == "items")
        {
          this.items = value;

        }
        else if (key == "updatedBy")
        {
          this.updatedBy = value;
     
        } 
      });  
    });
  }
```

With hopes that I could just do this in each of the components

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Itinerary } from 'src/app/Models/itineary';
import { ItineraryService } from 'src/app/Services/Itineary/itinerary.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav-itinerarys-depatures',
  templateUrl: './side-nav-itinerarys-depatures.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav-itinerarys-depatures.component.css']
})
export class SideNavItinerarysDepaturesComponent implements OnInit {

 
  hotelBookings: Itinerary;
  

  constructor(private itineraryService : ItineraryService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.hotelBookings= this.itineraryService.hotelBookings;
   
  
  }
  }
```

This However is creating this error which I am not sure why or how to fix.
I understand that this means that everything is called continuously but I cannot find where or how.

```
core.js:4352 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at applyView (core.js:9461)
    at addViewToContainer (core.js:8899)
    at ViewContainerRef.insert (core.js:10181)
    at ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView (core.js:10127)
    at NgIf._updateView (common.js:3481)
    at NgIf.set ngIfElse [as ngIfElse] (common.js:3462)
    at setInputsForProperty (core.js:8787)
    at elementPropertyInternal (core.js:7831)
    at ɵɵproperty (core.js:14709)
    at SideNavItinerarysComponent_ng_template_21_Template (side-nav-itinerarys.component.html:59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this was due to a NGif tag within the html template in side-nav-iti as shown in last part of the error message. This error message can occur at any infinite loop/condition.